# Cron task firing but function not working

Tags: get-posts, wp-cron

I have a cron task scheduled for every hour and I can see in my monitor that it is running. But, the function below isn't doing what it's supposed to. I'm trying to get any post within 3 different custom post types that have a meta_key of "listing_status" and a meta_value of "active". Then, I compare some custom field data (a date field, "listing_expiration) to the current date and change the listing_status to "expired" if the set date is now in the past.
I can't figure out why it's not expiring the posts though...

```
     //auto-expire active listings every hour (if they are expired)
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'expire_listings' ) ) {
  wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'expire_listings' );
}

add_action( 'expire_listings', 'tps_expire_listings' );

//Checks all current listings (that can expire) to see if they are expired, and if so, mark them as such
function tps_expire_listings(){
    $active = array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type'=>array('audition','gig', 'classified'),
        'meta_key'=>'listing_status',
        'meta_value'=>'active',
        'posts_per_page'=> -1,
    );
    $unexpired = get_posts($active);
    foreach ($unexpired as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        if (function_exists('get_field')) {
            $expiresOn = strtotime(get_field('listing_expiration', get_the_ID()));//returns a date formatted in m/d/Y, then timestamp
        }
        $now = strtotime(date('m/d/Y'));
        if ($now >= $expiresOn) {
            update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'listing_status', 'expired');
        } else {
            update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'listing_status', 'active');
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out...

I needed to use `$post->ID` instead of `get_the_ID()`.

Comment: The reason why `get_the_ID` doesn't work is explained on the codex page for [`setup_postdata`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata), you are using a local version of `$post` and not the global.